Typo3 display content with no Transl.Orig
TYPO3V12 - I configured 6 languages ​​on my site:

English is the default one.
The 5 others as "secondary": Fallback is set to Fallback: Show default language if no translation exists

It works perfect but what I also need is to have, if needed, a block (a header, a text element, whatever) only in one specific language other than the default one. By example, I need a text block only displayed in spanish but not in english and other languages.
I tried: creating a block in english, then translate it to spanish, then hide the english version. That doesn't work:

Nothing appears in front-end.

seems you've configured strict translation mode. Using another mode might be a better solution in your case.

Hello David, what particular setting are you talking about ? I can confirm yo toy that all my languages are configured as "Fallback: Show default language if no translation exists".

Paolo, It's explained on this site: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-frontendlocalization/12.4/en-us/LocalizedContent/Index.html

Furthermore this page could be helpful: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-editors/main/en-us/Languages/Index.html

Hello David, I read the 2 links you gave me thank you. All my languages are configured with fallbackType: fallback and not in strict mode (I checked in config.yaml + in back-end "Sites" module) with English as fallback language. It works perfect but I just need to understand if an element can be displayed without having a Transl.Orig or with a Transl.Orig hidden. Because when I do, it doesn't display

Can it be because I use FLUIDTEMPLATE, styles.content.get and select.where = colPos = 0 to display all mya page content within my trposcript ?

There exists a special extension for this case, let us know if that's solving your issue: https://extensions.typo3.org/package/georgringer/extbase-with-no-l10n-parent

This ext is exactly what I was looking for! Nice! Unfortunatly, I still have the same behavior. Verty strange

I was a bit astonished, that the extension claims to solve the problem for extbase only. So that might be the issue you experience perhaps? Anyway it might be worth it to read the manual.
